# Xamarin Google Cloud Messaging Not Working

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, mono, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to setup a basic Xamarin app with push notifications for Android.  I followed the demo [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/) and all seemed to be going well.  The application log shows the registration token received using the following code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Gms.Gcm;
using Android.Gms.Gcm.Iid;

namespace HawkProject.Droid {
[Service(Exported = false)]
class RegistrationIntentService : IntentService
{
    static object locker = new object();

    public RegistrationIntentService() : base("RegistrationIntentService") {     }

    protected override void OnHandleIntent (Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Info ("RegistrationIntentService", "Calling InstanceID.GetToken");
            lock (locker)
            {
                var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance (this);
                var token = instanceID.GetToken (
                    "1015213323461", GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);

                Log.Info ("RegistrationIntentService", "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
                //SendRegistrationToAppServer (token);
                //Subscribe (token);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Debug("RegistrationIntentService", "Failed to get a registration token");
            Log.Debug("RegistrationIntentService", e.Message);

            return;
        }
    }

    void SendRegistrationToAppServer (string token)
    {
        // Add custom implementation here as needed.
    }

    void Subscribe (string token)
    {
        var pubSub = GcmPubSub.GetInstance(this);
        pubSub.Subscribe(token, "/topics/hawkglobal", null);
    }
}
}
```

Application Log returns:

```
[RegistrationIntentService] Calling InstanceID.GetToken
[RegistrationIntentService] GCM Registration Token: dz8yxsF61tc:APA91bFpHBPsJuGUN2Yh5Hv9CyuAgyIUP4qthhNE79rJUOvLH__ildlVOaP9Q-X1lBpDk69BDRbnzDl4kdEdJBjyudwiVfRZnVR4trQwcM8JZYIEqMNFiXAy61RSjD2MWnC2kmNLj1Ev
```

My manifest is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="com.gcs.hawkproject" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="start">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.gcs.hawkproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<permission android:name="com.gcs.hawkproject.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<application android:label="Hawk" android:icon="@drawable/log"></application>
<application android:label="RemoteNotifications" android:icon="@drawable/Icon">
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" 
              android:exported="true" 
              android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.gcs.hawkproject" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="com.gcs.hawkproject.MyGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.gcs.hawkproject.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
</manifest>
```

All seems to be going well, but when i try to send a message, I get the following results:

POST:

```
{
    "data" : { "message" : "This is a test" },
    "to" : "dz8yxsF61tc:APA91bFpHBPsJuGUN2Yh5Hv9CyuAgyIUP4qthhNE79rJUOvLH__ildlVOaP9Q-X1lBpDk69BDRbnzDl4kdEdJBjyudwiVfRZnVR4trQwcM8JZYIEqMNFiXAy61RSjD2MWnC2kmNLj1Ev"
}
```

RESPONSE

```
{
    "multicast_id":5139152955408512939,
    "success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,
    "results": [{"error":"NotRegistered"}]
}
```

Any thoughts?  I am new to both Xamarin and GCM, so I am fumbling around for hours with no success.

I have other code from the demo as well that i can post if necessary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Experiencing the exact same problem. Did you resolv this?

Comment: You might want to check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513614/google-cloud-message-not-registered-failure-and-unsubscribe-best-practices

Answer (score 2):

Change

`using Android.Gms.Gcm.Iid;`

to

`using Android.Gms.Iid;`

Comment: Working for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest try the following:

(1) Uninstall and Reinstall the application, get a new notification token from GCM, try push to the new token again.

(2) Double check the Project id "1015213323461", is it possible that the sender_id does not match with the server certificate used to send the notification?

(3) com.gcs.hawkproject is this project id matching the one you registered in Google Developer console?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Xamarin Studio deployment issue that result in those NotRegistered errors, my workaround is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41087753/3419770).

Answer (score 0):

Is this is a new GCM project? You should be now using FCM - Firebase Cloud Messaging.

From GCM website:

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits
>   the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! See
>   the FAQ to learn more. If you are integrating messaging in a new app,
>   start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM,
>   in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.

I think that your GCM key might not be valid now. You should create your FCM project in here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/