# GCM - Device not registrered despite returned token

Tags: android, xamarin, google-cloud-messaging

In my Xamarin Android app I call

```
var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance(this);
string token = instanceID.GetToken("xxx", GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);
```

and I get a token in return in the format e63498f:oijafa89fjaasi...

In my c# program I call

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "key=xxxx");

            //Get current connection
            string url = "https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

            var message = new JObject();
            var data = new JObject();

            data.Add("message", "hello from csharp");
            message.Add("to", "e63498f:oijafa89fjaasi...");
            message.Add("data", data);

            HttpResponseMessage response = null;

            try
            {
                response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(message.ToString(), Encoding.Default, "application/json"));
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.Message);
                return;
            }

            //Handle errors
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + response.ToString());

            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            textBox2.Text = responseBody;
```

I get the response:

```
{Text = "{\"multicast_id\":xxxx,\"success\":0,\"failure\":1,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"error\":\"NotRegistered\"}]}"}
```

I have tryed alot of things but I cannot get it working. If I use the old GCM (gcm.register) there is no error message, but I don't want to use deprecated functionality. Why does GCM say that the token is not registrered when I just got a token returned from GCM? (The app is of course open while I do the test). Do I need to call some sort of method to actually register the token?

Comment: Ok, I have found that bug a ton of times, there are two cases: 1-You've used the ID too fast, give 5-10 seconds at least from the moment you got the token to the moment you use it. 2-Tokens get "corrupted" (invalidated? deprecated?) with debug builds (does it checks the signature? no idea), delete the current token, wait 10 seconds, register a new one and use it, it will work.

Comment: Gusman: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this similar [thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58416/a-resolution-to-frustrating-not-registered-responses-from-google-cloud-messaging) regarding GCM in the Xamarin forums that discusses the same issue. Mentioned in the thread ***"The problem seems to be that deployments to the VM may be triggering the uninstall scenario."***. A workaround/solution is also included:

"The solution I came up with was to track tokens where I receive a `Not Registered` response on the server, if a device indicates they want to use that token I respond with a send-a-new-token response. The way to accomplish this is to delete the `InstanceId` and then trigger the registration service

[Google cloud message 'Not Registered' failure and unsubscribe best practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513614/google-cloud-message-not-registered-failure-and-unsubscribe-best-practices/34536615#34536615)"

Care to try it out. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you. This was indeed the case.